# Android Studio : the buttons go outside the screen when shrinking the screen size

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to develop a calculator app and use GridLayout to organize the buttons. When the screen size is larger than 5.5 inches it works perfectly but when I shrink it to less than 5.5 inches all the button goes outside and become very weird. I have attached the xml file of main_activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
tools:context="com.example.songwei.calculator.MainActivity">

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="6"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/display"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="50sp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="AC"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_root"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="√"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:text="del"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_division"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:text="÷"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_7"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="#696969"
        android:text="7"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_8"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="#696969"
        android:text="8"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_9"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="#696969"
        android:text="9"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_multiply"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:text="×"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_4"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="#696969"
        android:text="4"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_5"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="#696969"
        android:text="5"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_6"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="#696969"
        android:text="6"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_subtraction"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:text="-"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="#696969"
        android:text="3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="#696969"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="#696969"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"

        android:backgroundTint="#696969"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_dot"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="#696969"
        android:text="."
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_equal"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:text="="
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />


    </GridLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And what is the mini size of the button and does that affect?

Answer (score 0):

try to make each number of buttons in one viewGroup (Like LinearLayout Horizontal or vertical) this depend on what your calculate looks like.
also use (layout_weight) to make size of view change depend on height and width.

sorry for not writing code.